# Constraint layout: Textview text overlap button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm facing this problem for the first time, my text overlap the button, i tried using barrier,guidelines but get text on center of button and start parent. I'm achieving the textViews text will be start on parent and end on before button and button always stay on end of parent like below picture.
[image]

My layout.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:text="title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/copyImageView"
            android:tint="?android:textColorSecondary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set the width to 0dp which means **match_constraint**
and also constraint its end to the start of ImageView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:text="title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/copyImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <ImageView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/copyImageView"
            android:tint="?android:textColorSecondary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

All you need is just a little margin and right constraint

now in your `descriptionTextView` first you need to set `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` so this don't go beyond layout and set some margin form the right side like  `android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"`

now you need to set the constraint with `ImageView` like this

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/copyImageView"`

now above line will always keep your text view from overlapping

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur erererereradipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/copyImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/copyImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_content_copy_black_24dp"
        android:tint="?android:textColorSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That also a good solution but mr. svkaka solution is easy. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" is what i search. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add icon to TextView end by adding drawable right/end. Use below code to add drawable to TextView. You can also set drawable padding to make space between drawable and text.

`android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon"`

Comment: That seems a good solution but i will stick with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem i ended up with below code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="tetetetetetetetetetetetetetetetetetetete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvWriteReview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWriteReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```